# Minecraft directory doesn't have a 'Resource Packs' folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I go into my .minecraft folder and there's Assets and all the other files and folders, but no resource packs folder?

If I create one manually, and place the textures inside, they don't show up in-game.

I'm on a Mac.

Comment: could you just create one?

Comment: if i create one and put my texture packs in it doesn't show on the game?

Comment: If you rename `.minecraft` to, say, `.minecraft-old`, then run the game (forcing it to redownload everything) and start a new (temporary) world, does it create the folder then?

Comment: that worked!!!!!

Comment: Good to hear! I've rolled back your question change, and added my suggestion as a full answer. On Arqade we prefer to keep them separate :). You can mark the answer as 'accepted' if you wish, by clicking the tick underneath the vote count :)

Comment: @Quayde if +Robotnik helped you, he created an answer for that. You can put an accept mark, so it may help others in the future.

Comment: I didn't understood the amount of DV on this question o.o

Answer (score 4):

If you rename the `.minecraft` folder temporarily to say, `.minecraft-old`, then run the game, this will force it to redownload everything. Then, start a new (temporary) world, and exit. This should recreate the missing folder.

After you've done this, you can copy your old worlds from the `.minecraft-old` directory into the new `.minecraft` directory.

Answer (score 0):

In order to locate the folder, you may go into the game, navigate to options then resource packs. At the bottom the screen there should be a button that says "Open Resource pack folder" Click that and the folder will open.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't open anything because there is no folder in .minecraft called resourcepacks

Comment: The folder should be created when you install minecraft. Attempt to make a clean reinstall and see what happens. If it still doesnt create a folder then im stumped.

Comment: so ur saying to delete my mine craft and the folder and reinstall it again?

Comment: Yes. Always remember to back up your worlds before doing so to prevent losing it.